# Redirect issue for Meta

Tags: feature-request, bug, meta

I understand that mathematics.stackexchange.com

redirects to

math.stackexchange.com to include non-Americans (such as me), but

mathematics.meta.stackexchange.com does **not** redirect to the Meta and gives a 404.

In a similar way, maths.stackexchange.com redirects to the main site, but

maths.**meta**.stackexchange.com does not.

I'm a big URL-typer and it took me a second to work this out.

This has been going for a while now; please can it be fixed?

[image: 404]

[image: 4042]

Comment: It might be somewhat of an accident that the alias even exists. IIRC, "mathematics.SE"  used to direct to MO before this site even existed; at some point that was changed. // Added see http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/919/mathematicsstackexchangecom-redirect/ for confirmation of that claim.

Comment: The meta SE forums underwent a URL renaming about two years ago.  Some of the broken link issues that came up are reflected in [this Meta Math.SE post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/rendering-of-some-past-links-to-meta-seems-to-be-broken-after-recent-changing-of) from shortly after that implementation.  I'm not clear what relationship there is between using the longer URL mentioned and being "non-American", but note the entirely separate [Mathematica Stack Exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://maths.stackexchange.com also redirects to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://maths.meta.stackexchange.com/ also doesn't redirect to Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche ah yes. Based on that somebody once proposed one should also have mathsoverflow.net as an alternative URL.

Comment: I think @quid would be referring to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/560/improving-anglo-american-relations

Comment: @quid It was a mistake, but it's now status-completed:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/please-point-mathematics-stackexchange-com-to-here-instead-of-to-mathoverflow

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for the info, edited question.

Comment: So... a couple things. I don't *think* this is related to the URL changes for meta. meta.math.stackexchange.com redirects to meta just fine, so if the other aliases *existed* (that is, meta.mathematics.stackexchange.com), they'd probably still redirect... but they don't. I'm guessing, though, that we just didn't ever connect the aliases anywhere to metas, only to the main sites. None of the aliases I've tried work for metas, so it's not just y'all. So, this may be by design but I'll check.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Catija then the design is flawed.

Comment: @Catija Any news on status?

Comment: Nothing to report. It's on a list.

Comment: @Catija List of... what, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: List of stuff to look into. I'm going to be honest, in the grand scheme of things, it's pretty low priority and, as I mentioned... it's probably been this way for years, possibly by design so I'm not sure we're necessarily going to fix it. The fact it's been unreported so long speaks to it being low urgency.

Comment: @Catija  Can you link the list or is it hush-hush mod stuff?

Comment: Internal Trello board. Sorry. But it gets triaged and we should get to it eventually.

Comment: Hi @Catija, I was wondering if there's been any update on this?